# How do I get a column with alternating functions applied with SQL?

Tags: sql

Example Data:

```
Fruit      Price
Apple      1         
Apple      4
Apple      5     
Orange     3   
Orange     7 
Orange     10             
Pear       2      
Pear       7
```

I want to use use SQL to get this table:

```
Fruit      Price       

Apple      1
Apple      5
Orange     3
Orange     10
Pear       2
Pear       7
```

so basically i want to have two records of each fruits, with the min price and the max price. Im working with SAP HANA

Comment: I am really having an issue understanding what you are trying to say. Are you trying to make a table? Or are you trying to query the table? Please clarify what you have and what you want a little better.

Comment: I want to query the first table to get a table that looks like the second table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a union like so:

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bfc104/4/0

```
select fruit, min(price) as price
from table_name
group by fruit
union all
select fruit, max(price)
from table_name
group by fruit
order by fruit, price
```

If some fruits have only one price, use UNION rather than UNION ALL, which will eliminate duplicates:

```
select fruit, min(price) as price
from table_name
group by fruit
union
select fruit, max(price)
from table_name
group by fruit
order by fruit, price
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that will do what you want and used your sample data as test.

using a temp table

```
create table #fruits
(
  idFruit int identity (1,1) not null,
  Fruit varchar(25) default null,
  Price decimal default null,
  guidFruit uniqueidentifier default newsequentialid(),
  dtCreate datetime default getutcdate()
)
```

using SQL 2008R2 + one statement insert.

```
INSERT into #fruits (Fruit, Price)
VALUES
  ('Apple', 1),
  ('Apple', 4),
  ('Apple', 5),
  ('Orange', 3),
  ('Orange', 7),
  ('Orange', 10),
  ('Pear',   2),
  ('Pear',   7);
```

show you have all the data in a table

```
select * from #fruits;
```

now build you output query with only min/max
yes we could have build it with a CTE but they might not have that functionality

```
select
 mm.Fruit,
 mm.Price
from
(
  select
   f.Fruit,
   min(f.Price) as [Price]
  from
    #fruits f
  group by 
    f.fruit
  union all
  select
   f.Fruit,
   max(f.Price) as [Price]
  from
    #fruits f
  group by 
    f.fruit
) as mm
order by
 mm.Fruit asc,
 mm.Price asc;
```